# Tesla Api - 404 error trying to use refresh_token

Tags: python, tesla

I've been scratching my head over this bug for the last hour and was wondering if anyone could help me out. Here is the link to the tesla api: https://tesla-api.timdorr.com/api-basics/authentication

I've been trying to make a `POST` request to get a new `access_token` like such

```
data = urlencode({
            "grant_type": "refresh_token", "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET, "refresh_token": refresh_token
        }).encode("utf-8")
    request = Request("https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oath/token",
                      data=data)
    response = urlopen(request).read()
```

However, this keeps returning me a 404 error but I would like to think that I am making the POST request correctly. Can someone point out what I'm missing here? I'm confident that all my variables (`CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET`, etc) are correct too

Would appreciate any help :-)

Thanks!

Comment: `oath` -> `oauth`

Comment: @KlausD. oh my.... thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't catch this...Legit stuck on this for an hour and was completely baffled. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: 404 means bad URL.